# Loop through visualization in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

So I want to have a visualization that is basically a table form, but with visualizations that loop for each customer, is there a control or visual that I can use to do this in powerbi? Please see the drawing to understand what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether Power BI can dynamically create extra visuals in a report, based on unique values for each customer, then the answer is no (at least, not with Power BI Desktop out of the box tools).

This scenario is commonly solved by either

- creating one set of visuals, then using the Customer in a slicer and selecting one customer at a time, OR
- creating a set of visuals for each Customer manually and filtering the set to the desired customer.

If you want to compare several customers on the same report screen, you could create several sets of visuals and use slicers for each set to determine which customer is showing in that set.